# Adding new Tab Views Dynamically

Tags: android

I'm new to android development. I already tried to search for answers for almost two days but I have no luck. Is it possible to add new Tab Views based on the tables in your database? I'm trying to create an app where the users can create new table to store new data. Then display the data from that new table to a new Tab View. Is it possible? If yes, I hope you can give me some Ideas on how I can implement it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible though very hard and may create memory leak if the data is coming from a server. All you have to do is call the results and set them in the adapter of your tabs.